# NGXS selectSnapshot not returning next state

Tags: angular, local-storage, state, ngxs

I have defined an action where I get auth data from the backend and patch it to the state:

```
@Action(Login)
login({ patchState }: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, { payload }: Login) {
    return this.loginService.loginUser(payload).pipe(tap((result: { token: string }) => {
      patchState({ token: result.token, username: payload.userName });
    }));
  }
```

And than store it in the localStorage:

```
NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({
  key: [
    'auth.token',
  ]
})
```

In my `login component`:
`this.store.dispatch([new Login(this.loginForm.value)]);`

Now in my `token-interceptor`, I want to access the actual value of the token stored in the localStorage, using the `Storage plugin`:

`const token = this.store.selectSnapshot<string>(AuthState.token);`
This always returns the previous state. The store is being updated, but the updated value is never returned using selectSnapshot. 
So what is the best way to access the actual (updated/`next state`) value from the store?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with the interceptor. It's doing the right thing by reading the snapshot. The problem is that a HTTP request was made **before** the state has been updated. You have to wait until `this.store.dispatch([new Login(this.loginForm.value)])` has completed.

Comment: I guess you have to create an example on the codesandbox or stackblitz. No1 knows what you're doing in your app

Comment: @Reactgular this is what I thaught first and tried: 
`@Action(Login)
  async login({ patchState }: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, { payload }: Login) {
    await this.loginService.loginUser(payload).pipe(tap((result: { token: string })=> {

      patchState({token: result.access_token, username: payload.userName, });
    }));
  }` 
And it did not worked. 
I have also tried `await this.store.dispatch(new Login(this.loginForm.value)).subscribe(data => console.log(data));` wish did not worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a toPromise() at the end of the api call ( and pipe ). as such:

```
Action(Login)
async login({ patchState }: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, { payload }: Login) {
 await this.loginService.loginUser(payload).pipe(tap((result: { token: string })=> { 
        patchState({token: result.access_token, username: payload.userName, }); })).toPromise(); 
}
```

Make sure you await the store dispatch before reading the snapshot value.

```
await this.store.dispatch([new Login(this.loginForm.value)]).toPromise();
```

Now read the snapshot value. 
If you require reading the snapshot in a different location than the one that dispatched the action, Then try using the store select to get the updated version of the store token and username at that location ( instead of reading the snapshot ).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is almost what I ended up doing, but without making the action async.

Comment: I don't know I'm not the one who did it... I just upvoted it...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it:

```
async loginfunc() {
  await this.store.dispatch(new Login(this.loginForm.value)).toPromise();
}
```

the state action remain the same.